# jQuery ajax POST always return error

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my jQuery ajax function

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'MY_CGI_SERVER/cgi-bin/test.cgi',
            type: 'POST',
            data: '{"type": "appStore","command": "GET","user": "John","passwd": "123456","deviceID": "123456789","count": "0","page": "1", "content": "basic","sortBy": "rate","byAppID": "false","appIDList": ""}',
            success: function(response){
                alert("OK!\n");
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error){
                alert(xhr);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It always return error function, but I use wireshark to capture the packages,
the data is post successfully, also the response.

The package is as below:

[image: enter link description here]

What is wrong??

Comment: not sure, add contentType:"application/json" that work?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Looks like the _test.cgi_ script doesn't properly respond to your AJAX request. What does it return anyway? EDIT: Ok, the server responds with a 200 OK header. Tell us which error jquery returns to you?

Comment: by the code, type: 'GET'

Comment: I added the contentType:"application/json", the result is the same, but the HTTP Verbs change to OPTIONS.

The alert content is [object Object].

Comment: If `"type": "appStore"` and others are supposed to be request parameters, than you should remove `'` from `data: `

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove single quotations around the data value

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'MY_CGI_SERVER/cgi-bin/test.cgi',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {"type": "appStore","command": "GET","user": "John","passwd": "123456","deviceID": "123456789","count": "0","page": "1", "content": "basic","sortBy": "rate","byAppID": "false","appIDList": ""},
            success: function(response){
                alert("OK!\n");
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error){
                alert(xhr);
            }
        });
    });
```

If you are still facing problem then the error triggered because your cgi outputs or prints json string two times or something nonjson, which conflicts the syntax of json. Always output single line or at least maintain syntax by concatenating

To check whether your error function outputs the valid json data or somewhat

loop through all of xhr

```
$.each(xhr, function(key, value) {
  alert(key + ": " + value);
});
```

Comment: The xhr content is readyState:0, responseText: , status:0, statusText:error,

Comment: check near "byAppID": "false","appIDList": ""}', you are providing nothing for appIDList, try providing some value for this parameter and check again, also remove single quotations around the data

Comment: I removed the single quotations, and providing values for appIDList, the result is the same. Actually, my server only accept POST and the format is json format. If I remove the single quotation, server will reject the request.

Comment: access this page directly, pass the contents in query string and see what cgi tells you

Answer (score 0):

My server side is programing by Perl.

Because ajax always go to the error function, so I hard code the Response data.

This is my server side code for response.

```
sub SendResponse()
{
    $response = shift;

    print header('application/json; charset=utf-8');
    print '{"test":"123","123":"test"}';
}
```